# Being explicit with ToolTip

Tags: website-design, forms, user-behavior, wireframe, user-expectation

If we are gonna take in data from users(say mail id), and also if we are accepting more than one entry from the user, how can the tooltip be shown? It can either be explicit or can be made visible on hover. But which one would be more appreciable with respect to ux?

Comment: How would users who access your application with keyboard-only trigger this tooltip? Or on touch-screen devices?

Comment: I argue that tooltips are usually irrelevant. Either the data is important enough to be placed on-screen to begin with, or, if not, it's probably not worth showing at all--even in a tooltip.

Comment: @DA01 I find tooltip style hints very useful for providing context specific information without cluttering a form. It is great to be able to only give text hints for the specific field the user is currently typing in. If I put all the text for each field onto the form it would be cluttered and confusing. If I left out the text entirely the user would be without help/feedback. Other uses: allowing novice users of more complicated applications to discover advanced user tricks without using the manual / help section of an application (e.g. shortcut keys for performing common actions faster).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a tooltip to the right of the field (if there's room) that provides a hint about what's expected in the field. The tooltip appears when the field receives focus, whether it's by clicking or by tabbing into it.

Advanced versions may use the tooltip for validation.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cz5Q6/

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an explicit tooltip, displayed above  the text box (a little speech bubble thing) when it has focus (i.e. The cursor is in the text box).

Important information should never be dependant on hover, as this is not accessible to users that aren't using a mouse (as JonW already pointed out in his comment).